# How to avoid using + in version number with SQLiteAssetHelper

Tags: android, sqlite, android-gradle-plugin, android-sqlite, build.gradle

I am using the SQLiteAssetHelper class to manage an SQLite database in my app.

To do this I have followed the instructions on how to use SQLiteAssetHelper on GitHub, which is to add `compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'` to my dependencies in my build.gradle file.

However, when I do this, android studio gives me a yellow warning, which says `avoid using + in version numbers; can lead to unpredictable and unrepeatable builds`

Sounds ominous *Gulp*

but this GitHub page, which I will post below, doesn't offer a version number, it just says to add  `compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'`

Should I just leave the +? or is there a better way to do this?

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Comment: It is better if you specify an exact version number. Unfortunately, it is difficult to determine this for some libraries.

Comment: Basically its just warning you that the `+` will always get you the latest version and those changes might break stuff and you were not expecting it. where as with a specific version you always get that versions code and nothing new until you decide to change the version yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on the [releases tab](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/releases), you can see that the most recent release is 2.0.1. It is better that you specify this explicitly in order to have predictable builds.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'
```

[This site - "Gradle, please"](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/#sqliteassethelper) - can be helpful sometimes.