# build.gradle warning 'avoid using + in version numbers'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, libraries, android-appcompat

This is my `build.gradle` app-level file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "it.myco.app.myproj"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Android Studio highlights the line

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
```

with the message

> avoid using + in version numbers can lead to unpredictable and
>   unrepeatable builds

This line is auto-generated by Android Studio. Why this warning message? What I need to write to solve the warning ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid using + in version number with SQLiteAssetHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39710042/how-to-avoid-using-in-version-number-with-sqliteassethelper)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Someday, someone else may do a `git pull` on your code and then try build an apk. This apk may have different behavior or even get a build error or run time error, because the dependencies version can be different than the dependencies used when you created this code.

You should use an explicit dependency version. I suggest use the newest version. You can search on [bintray jcenter](http://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter) to see the newest version. If you are using Android Studio, `File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> (your module, app usually) -> Dependencies -> Add library dependency (click the + sign)` will give you the newest version, even add library automatically.

Comment: This answer gives a concrete scenario to explain what is going wrong. Then goes further to show how to get the latest dependency. I just did a small edit to improve the wording.

Comment: @RickMajpruz Thanks, and sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: I am unclear how to navigate to `Dependencies -> Add library dependency`. Presumably I should bring up the `Project Structure` tab but then what? I don't see a menu entry at the top and I tried right-clicking but I don't see `Dependencies` in in context menu. Perhaps this should be a separate question. I am using Android Studio 2.3.3.

Comment: @RickMajpruz Choose `Modules -> app` first. It should be `Project structure -> app(module) -> Dependencies -> Add library dependency`

Comment: Just one little extra tip to readers. You can bring up the **Project Structure** window with `File -> Project Structure` from the top-level menu of Android Studio.

Comment: @RickMajpruz No problem. 举手之劳

Comment: Yes, I sensed why of the warning. The real thing I do not understood is how retrieve the last version of the libraries. This answer explain well the point.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace it with the latest version of the library. Usually AS shows the latest version when you `alt + enter` on the warning.

[More info on the reasons](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/09/09/dont-use-dynamic-versions-for-your-dependencies/)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use + in dependency version. it means Android studio will use the latest library, which may cause problem in future. In android studio it's recommended to use all android library with same version, suppose you are using + and if any single library got updated then android studio will use that updated library, so the version for this library will be change. that cause problem to build application.

That's why gradle giving this warning. it's best practice to write full version number instead of +.

Comment: "This line is auto-generated by Android Studio."

Answer (score 1):

It's a normal warning.

It's better you to choose a concrete version than going that way. This is because if you use "+" it will choose the newest, so in the new version it's possible you to get some deprecated or unexpected changes that will do your app to die. Think that if you are using it in a huge project you will have a lot of dependencies so it will be a chaotic environment.

Use specific versions and if there is a new one... update it manually.

To solve the warning and choose the last version, if you are using Windows, click Alt+Enter and it will choose the latest version.

If it doesn't work you will have to search for it on the Internet or in Project Structure > Modules >(your module) > Dependencies > +

Comment: Never call warnings "normal"...

Answer (score 1):

> Why this warning message?

Here you can find a [good blog](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/09/09/dont-use-dynamic-versions-for-your-dependencies/) about this topic.

**Dynamic versions add nondeterminism to your build**:

- Dependencies can unexpectedly introduce behavior changes to your app.
- The same source built on two
  different machines can differ.
- Similarly, builds built on the same machine but
  at different times can differ.
- Past builds cannot be
  reproduced perfectly. This makes it difficult to revert safely.
- There
  are security implications if a bad actor introduces a malicious
  version of a dependency.

> What I need to write to solve the warning ?

**Always specify your dependency versions explicitly.**

Comment: This is also a very good answer like the other that I marked as solution.