# Unable to implement image cropping

Tags: java, android-studio, android-manifest

When I synced API 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+', then it underlines implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0':

```
enter dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
    api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'


}
```

Comment: Probably they're implementing different versions of this `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0` dependency. Hover over the red line it should show what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your use-case? and you have image in which format? (Bitmap, Uri or it's in blop storage)
Why not resize the image rather than cropping?

here is code for resizing if the image is in a bitmap, if it helps

```
 /**
 * reduces the size of the image
 * @param image
 * @param maxSize
 * @return
 */
fun getResizedBitmap(image: Bitmap, maxSize: Int): Bitmap {
    var width: Int = image.width
    var height: Int = image.height

    val bitmapRatio: Double = (width / height).toDouble()
    if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
        width = maxSize
        height = (width / bitmapRatio).toInt()
    } else {
        height = maxSize
        width = (height * bitmapRatio).toInt()
    }
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true)
}
```

Comment: First, read the question, please. OP is not asking for implementation. Gradle is unable to sync the project.

Answer (score 0):

You are using gradle dependency which contains bigger version than you have for support compat **28.0.0**. Meaning probably last included dependency, contains bigger version than you have it. Also please get avoid using **.+** in the end of dependency version. Get ride of it and replace it with actual version e.g.: "2.8.0". It should be replaced because it can ruin your build at some point. Check here for more: **[build.gradle warning 'avoid using + in version numbers'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46793888/build-gradle-warning-avoid-using-in-version-numbers)**

```
api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
```

Replace with:

```
api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'
```

Also try to replace you support version with newer one or consider about using android X dependencies:

```
implementation androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0
```

Try to stay in flow with technologies, use latest versions! :)